# What is the major product of the nitration of N,N-dimethylaniline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds

What is the major product when *N*,*N*-dimethylaniline, $\ce{C6H5N(CH3)2}$, reacts with concentrated nitric acid (conc. $\ce{HNO3}$) in presence of concentrated sulphuric acid (conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$)?

Here, nitrogen  gets protonated. So, it becomes deactivating, but it can't be stabilised by resonance because it would exceed valency of nitrogen. So, is *meta* or *para* the major product?